# CodenameOne Final Variable error with iOS

Tags: variables, codenameone, final

I have a piece of code working as expected in Android but not in iOS. Problem is the value of the final variable 'nombre' which in Android gets the expected value, whereas in iOS it gets a different one randomly chosen from the list (specified in codesnippet provided)

```
public AsignarNombreCDF(){
    this.departamentoId = AdministradoresApp.departamentoId;
    this.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
    this.setTitle("Asignar Nombre a CDF");
    TopBarUtils.addMenuToTopbar(this);
    TopBarUtils.addCommandToTopbarMenu(this, "Inicio Departamento", e->{new MenuDepartamento(departamentoId).show();});
    try {
        Map m = Utils.consultaWebService("newfoldernames", new Object[]{"department", departamentoId});
        String folderNameMatrix = (String) m.get("FolderNameMatrix");
        Map m_ = (Map) JSONUtils.fromJsonString(folderNameMatrix);
        Iterator it = m_.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String k = (String) it.next();
            final String nombre = (String) m_.get(k);
            Button b = new Button(nombre);
            b.addActionListener(e->{cargarFotos(nombre);});
            this.add(b);
        }
        int y = 2;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Utils.gestionaExceptionUi(ex);
    }

}
```

Problem is that the final variable nombre seems not to assign correctly to the value passed to the button listener. This as already said, only happens in IOS and not in Android, where we never get a mismatch. Any chance that the iOS build system might oversee this situation?. Any ideas how to overcome the problem?

Regards.
Carlos.

Comment: Is the value for the button and the event different? E.g. button title `1` and action event acts as if it's `2`? This is pretty basic stuff and I have a lot of code that looks like that so I doubt that's possible. I'm guessing there's an error in a different area of the code.

Comment: Hi Shai, that's exactly what is happening. I click on button 1 but event is fired as if 2 was clicked. It looks as a build issue to me. If you want I can provide a video demonstrating the problem. Regards.

Comment: Sounds more like a race condition. What's the code of `cargarFotos`? Is this code running on the EDT?